# Posting price for New, Reconditioned and Repair

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, extensions, php-5.4

[image][image]

Hello everyone! I'm attempting to create this function in magento yet I'm a little confused as how to start or where to put the code, please help! The code I've added is what I have so far but I'm not sure how correct it is or if it'll do what I need it too.

Comment: You need to change product view template. But better start with complete video tutorials from Ben Marks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4MzdqVV9V8&list=PLY_U2aJagyKQN58Cw7Tecm-sgPneeyJm8

Comment: Yes I had some of idea of having to work there, but how could I set up the function in such a way to call to the product and display the prices/messages when necessary?

Comment: with Conditional Statements - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: the image I've added is of the code I have for what I think would work.